# panel is covering windows

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager, display-manager, panel

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and sometimes the panel covers the bottom of windows where I need to access the buttons on the bottom.

I'm trying to do a restore using `timeshift` because of another issue I'm having to install stuff, and I can't because of this problem.

I've tried resizing the panel and moving its placement, but that hasn't worked. Still can't see the bottom of the window. Any advise would be appreciated!

Comment: When you say "windows", are you referring to the operating system from Microsoft? I'm asking because you have also tagged your question with [tag:windows], which refers to interoperability issues with Microsoft Windows. Could you mention something about what Linux you are running (or is that "Linux Lite"?) and what display manager you're using? Since this is an issue where actually seeing what you are seeing would be helpful, could you add a (sensibly cropped) screenshot that highlights the issue?

Comment: Not running windows...this is my version of linux - Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. i"m talking about the timeshift restore application window.

Comment: What window manager / desktop (@Kusalananda did you mean window manager, the desktop manager does little more that login, as far as I know).

Comment: I did not like the default window-manager / desktop, of Ubuntu, so I switched to KDE plasma. You just need to install it, then the easiest way to start it is to logout and back in again (selecting the new desktop).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The user is giving information in comments little by little. I've been updating the question and tags for them as information appears. I'll stop this now though as I don't really have the time to do so. And oh, that last comment was from you, not the user.  Sigh...

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda. Stephan Landry you can edit the question yourself. Can you address any comments, to make it clearer.

Comment: how do I add a screenshot to this? i'll show you what I mean!

Comment: I think I figured out the problem....I loaded linux on my netbook and it has an odd native resolution. I happened to connect an external display which had a more common resolution and I was able to see all of the window and complete my restore via timeshift. I'm going to chalk this problem up to being do to the funky native resolution of my acer d255e netbook. Thanks!